# Dueling Network gradient with respect to Advantage stream

Tags: reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

Looking at [Dueling DQN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjsY8-P4WHM):

$Q = V + A - mean(A)$

For simplicity, let's assume we are working with 4 neurons. Recall that Value stream only has 1 neuron $(v_0)$

Re-writing the above equation, we get:

$$
 \left[  \begin{array}{c}
 Q_0\\Q_1\\Q_2\\Q_3
\end{array}
\right] = 
\left[  \begin{array}{c}
 v_0\\v_0\\v_0\\v_0
\end{array}
\right] +
 \left[  \begin{array}{c}
 a_0\\a_1\\a_2\\a_3
\end{array}
\right] -
 \left[  \begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{N}(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3)
\\\frac{1}{N}(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3)
\\\frac{1}{N}(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3)
\\\frac{1}{N}(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3)
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Question:**

V (the Value) is a usual Dense Layer which has 1 neuron at the output.

A (the Advantage) is a usual Dense Layer which has N neurons at the output - what is the correct gradient vector to be passed to the neurons of this Advantage stream?

---

**Thoughts:**

From [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/248941/187816) post:

> Since Q is a simple sum of functions you have:
>
> $$\nabla_{\theta} Q(s,a) = \nabla_{\theta}V(s) + \nabla{\theta}A(s,a)
>  - \frac{1}{numActions} \sum_{a'}\nabla_{\theta}A(s, a')$$
>
> You get the gradients of the V and A networks as usual by backprop.

To me, the correct gradient vector to be passed to the advantage stream is:

$$gradForA = \frac{dE}{dQ}\frac{dQ}{dA}$$

however, the second fraction of the equation is what makes me puzzled.
Is it as simple as:

$$\frac{dQ}{dA} =  \left[  \begin{array}{c}
1-\frac{1}{N}\\1-\frac{1}{N}\\1-\frac{1}{N}\\1-\frac{1}{N}
\end{array}
\right] $$

It's probably not, especially if we look at the "mean" vector, in the example above.
We can see that its every entry contains contribution of **all** advantage neurons - because they are summed.

Am I doomed to perform 2 backpropagations for the advantage dense layer, in parallel? - One for $+A$ and one for $-mean(A)$.  I would then add-up (component-wise) the two gradient vectors. Sounds like a clumsy idea..

Comment: I may be completely wrong (never done any DQN) but you do backprop by building a directed graph.  By the time you calculated the gradient for $V$ you already passed through both $A$ and $mean(A)$ since these are needed to calculate the gradient of output w.r.t. $V$.  i.e. in the backwards pass anything that was added to $V$ to reach the output will have its grad already calculated. (Assuming reverse-mode autodiff).

Comment: Thank you @grochmal - $V$ and $A$ are 2 separate sibling layers computed in parallel (like two different mini nets working from a same input), they are not feeding into each other. We combine their answers manually afterwards, to obtain vector $Q$

Comment: Apologies if I sound like an idiot meddling where I do not understand (although that's probably true for DQNs).  But from you equation on $gradForA$ I believe you are calculating the error between the vector $Q$ and some target vector.  i.e. the loss function is $something(Q - target)$ (I may be wrong in this assumption).  You can start autodiff from any point in the loss calculation, i.e. do not backprop the network but backprop the loss function (backprop kind-off *is* autodiff).

Comment: No problems, - yes usually in RL we begin backpropagation by building-up from an original discrepancy such as $something(target - Q)$, and gradually peek into what's inside our Q, "descending down" through the layers of our network, multiplying more and more (according to the chain rule). However I can't use autodiff from the Loss, because I have a custom c++ implementation - I have to code backprop manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified the following formulas with [Gradient Checking](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/30850/43077), and it's confirming they are correct. (Getting discrepancy less than 0.00002)

Let's draw the tree diagram of what's affecting what:

[image]

If we try to find gradient affecting $a_0$, we have to sum-up the pink chains. They make it evident that $a_0$ has affected all $Q$ variables, thus we sum these chains.

So the formula for entire gradient that has to enter $A$ layer is:

$$ 
gradForA =  \left[  \begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\partial E}{\partial a_0}
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_1}
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_2}
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_3}
\end{array}
\right]  = \left[  \begin{array}{c}
 \\\frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_0}(1 - u) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_1}(-u)+ \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_2}(-u) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_3}(-u)
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_0}(- u) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_1}(1-u)+ \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_2}(-u) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_3}(-u)
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_0}(- u) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_1}(-u)+ \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_2}(1-u) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_3}(-u)
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_0}(- u) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_1}(-u)+ \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_2}(-u) + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_3}(1-u)
\end{array}
\right]
$$

where $u$ is $\frac{1}{N}$

---

**Bonus:**

By looking at the above image, we see that the $v_0$ has similarly affected all $Q$ variables, so its gradient is:
$$
gradForV = \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_0} + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_1}+ \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_2} + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_3}
$$

$gradForV$ is a scalar (not a vector) because value stream only has 1 neuron, always.

---

**Bonus #2**

to compute $gradForA$ it's obvious to do via 2 for-loops, nested in one another. However, you can get rid of nesting and improve code performance by re-writing the formula as follows:

$$ 
gradForA =  R + scalarB  
$$

where

$scalarB = (-u)(\frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_0} + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_1}+ \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_2} + \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_3})$

and

$$ R =  \left[  \begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_0} 
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_1} 
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_2} 
\\\frac{\partial E}{\partial Q_3}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The cool thing is that $scalarB$ can be computed once (it's a scalar), and re-used when computing the $gradForA$ vector.

Notice that $scalarB$ and $gradForV$ are almost the same thing, just with extra $(-u)$  So you can re-use this value in your code as well.

Comment: Does seem legit alright, +1.  If i'm not mistaken you are taking the negative on $-u$ from something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256595/is-there-any-significance-to-the-derivative-of-the-average)

Comment: Thanks! $u$ is a shorthand notation for $\frac{1}{N}$. It appears when we are trying to "peek via chain rule" into the mean $−\frac{1}{N}(a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3)$ In other words, for that particular part: $\frac{\partial E}{\partial a_0}$ is $(-\frac{1}{N})$